# SSAS - Date Dimension ties wrong dates to hierarchy

Tags: ssas, dimensional-modeling

I'm using my own date dimension instead of the MS generated date dimension. I've got a table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateDim]
(
[DateID] [int] NOT NULL,   --PK
[FullDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[QuarterOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[MonthOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[DayOfMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
)
```

Hierarchy created: Year, Quarter, Month, Day of Month

Relationships: DateDim->DayOfMonth->Month->Quarter->Year

Composite keys created for

```
  DayOfMonth: Year, Month, DayOfMonth;
  Month: Year, Month;
  Quarter: Year, Quarter;
```

However, after creating and processing this, I get Year, Quarter, Month, and Day, but the FullDate associated with each seems to only be associated at the "Day of Month" level. The actual date has no bearing on the hierarchy. I know I must be missing something along the way, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any pointers on how to set this up properly without creating redundant relationships or cloning columns? (I know the former is improper)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did wrong the first time, but when I re-created the dimension using fewer attributes, it processed correctly and all Full Date values matched the Year/Quarter/Month/Day Of Month hierarchy. As much as I'd like to know what I did wrong the first time, I'm not going to spend too much time trying to figure that out if it works when done correctly.